# How to filter month-wise data in an Microsoft Excel 2013?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a table like this,

[image]

I need `month-wise` **`pivot-table`** which calculates as following

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new column called Month which is calculated as =month(B4), for example, and use that as the basis for your pivot table.

Comment: Maybe a bit better to use TEXT function, e.g. =TEXT(B4,"MMM-YY") ?